# Adding a paper-scroll-header-panel within a paper-header-panel

Tags: polymer

As part of my page I have a list that I need to attach a scroll bar too. The entire page is within a paper-header-panel. If I give the paper-scroll-header-panel a height in pixels then it displays fine but otherwise, even if I set it to "width: 100%" it will not display. It seems it ought to be easier then I am trying to make it. are there any tips you can send along as to what I might be doing wrong?
David

```
<paper-header-panel class="flex">
    <paper-toolbar>
        <div>MyViewer</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div class="horizontal layout flex">
        <div class="flex">
            <paper-scroll-header-panel>
                <paper-toolbar>
                    <div>Hello</div>
                </paper-toolbar>
                <div>
                    <h4>here 1</h4>
                    <h4>here 2</h4>
                    <h4>here 3</h4>
                    <h4>here 4</h4>
                    <h4>here 5</h4>
                </div>
            </paper-scroll-header-panel>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Stuff</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</paper-header-panel>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `paper-scroll-header-panel` displays fine if you display it by itself. Maybe this is why it's not displaying in your sample:

The documentation for `paper-scroll-header-panel` says:
Important: The paper-scroll-header-panel will not display if its parent does not have a height.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-scroll-header-panel